# splash page animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this idea in my head that when my site loads, there's this line of text or image that says... i don't know, "hello"... then, after about 2 seconds or so, it smoothly and quickly slides to the right with my home page following it stopping when the page is centered with the browser window. My entire site slides left or right horizontally when you change pages. would anyone know how to accomplish this? thank you so much!

heres the code i'm using for my navigation for my site.
http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery

Comment: Having the entire page slide probably won't be as smooth as you'd like.

Comment: oh okay. well, i guess it wouldn't be the entire page. really it would be about a 100px by 100px image that would do the sliding. the background would stay the same.

Comment: So what's your question exactly? You gave a link to something you're already using...